how to convert baseband.bin file to raw codes?
I have a baseband.bin firmware of device Samsung Galaxy M21. I want to extract it into raw code format and re-edit it upload it to the phone.
Please help me, i don't know how to extract this firmware file into raw code format.

Probably more appropriate here: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+firmware
